# How to overlay an audio file with one image file for a YouTube-optimised video output from the command-line?

Tags: video, youtube

Is there a command-line tool that allows me to overlay an audio file with one image file and outputs a video file that is optimised for YouTube uploading purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, ffmpeg is a tool well suited for that task. There is even an official guide solving exactly your problem, see:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images.

Taken from the linked source:

> If you want to add audio (e.g. audio.wav) to one "poster" image, you need -shortest to tell it to stop after the audio stream is finished. The internal AAC encoder is used in this example, but you can use any other supported AAC encoder as well:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

> If your audio file is using a codec that the output container supports (e.g. MP3 audio in AVI or M4A/AAC audio in MP4), you can copy it instead of re-encoding, which will preserve the audio quality:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

I'll guess that h264 + AAC or MP3 is pretty good for Youtube, but in the end, they will take pretty much any format. Just be sure that you use an audio format with low compression, so a 64 kbit/s MP3 might not be the best idea.

Comment: Very nice answer. You're off to a great start on the site. Welcome!